How to cut a key? (limit linear extrapolation)
How can I set a start point for ''linear extrapolation''? For example: start from frame 250 then make same act until frame 400. When I choose linear extrapolation, it makes same act in the whole period, it makes endless but I need an end and a start
.

in graph editor


click on modifiers
add limits
enter the minx/maxx as you need it

